# Apache Performance Tuning - Apache HTTP Server

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat

I'm using Apache HTTP Server Project (2.2.X) and I'd like to attempt to do some performance tuning.

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
# uname -a
Linux 6app02a.uftmasterad.org 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Sep 14 05:32:37 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# rpm -q httpd php
httpd-2.2.15-29.el6_4.x86_64
php-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64
#
```

I'm running Pressflow (Drupal6) PHP based application and I also have a reverse proxy in front of it (varnish) and as far as PHP goes I have some caching mechanisms such as: APC, memcache to speed it up as well.

I'm starting from : [Apache Performance Tuning - Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/perf-tuning.html), however I'd like to get some input from other people who's using same project on how to tune it.

Currently I'm using following:

```
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15

<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
```

Please advise.

Comment: If you want feedback, you will need to post more details.  What are you testing?  Just apache, a web application? How are you testing? What results do you have and what are the goals?  You need more context for this to be a useful question.

Comment: @jeffatrackaid Thank you for commenting on my question and while I do understand that my question is rather a bit more "general" and not specific I've done some homework trying to tune it as much as I can (apc,memcache) however I'd like to see if I can do better and this time I'm concentrating on Apache http server itself.

Comment: You will need post more info along with configuration and initial results for this to be beneficial. Otherwise it will likely be closed as off-topic or too broad.

Comment: Do you have primarily authenticated users or anonymous users?

Comment: @HTTP500 both actually and as I mention before, we have varnish as a reverse proxy in front of apache (pressflow) so that takes care of anonymous traffic at least on some level, but I feel like bottle neck is PHP.